# REST api monitoring (Progress Openedge)

Tags: rest, monitoring, openedge, progress-4gl

Is there any monitoring tool for REST application(Progress Openedge) that can check:

- whether the service is up and running or not
- appserver is up and running
- hit count and other information for each api resources
- error logging
- customized reporting(such as sending report in mail)

I saw RESTMAN Utility in the documentation but couldn't find the details as i expected/needed. Can it do the things mentioned above? If yes, how to implement and customize it?
*(Progress version: 11.3)*

Answer (score 1):

Mahesh

I had a quick look in the current online OpenEdge documentation (which is for 11.7) and found this - https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/asadm/using-the-restman-utility.html

There are links to the functions that seem to show what you are looking for.

I haven't used it myself, but it looks like most of the Progress monitoring tools, so the issue you may have is that it provides "all" of the information that you need, but in a format that you have to parse before you get to the specific details you need.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be convincing to solve my problems. But i am now stuck in configuration part, oerm index page shows nothing(blank), dont know what i am missing. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As examples where I know that restmgr1 is the server:

Show if Restman Appserver is running

`restman -i restmgr1 -q`

Show all the deployed REST applications

`restman -i restmgr1 -list`